# Parcel: unable to marshal value android.widget.RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, serializable, parcel

I have a problem with a type of data(ArrayList of ViewGroup), that I want pass at a ResultActivity.class. This ViewGroup contains a layout block created via xml.

One of this block is already present in main layout managed of IPActivity class, its name in java code is mFirstBlock. After I insert mFirstBlock in arrayList. Then the user can add an equal new block with a button. All this blocks I add in arrayList.

This is layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_link_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...

    <EditText
        ...

    <TextView
        ...

    <EditText
        ...

    <ImageButton
        ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is java code:

```
public class IPActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String EXTRA_BLOCKS = "...";

    ArrayList<ViewGroup> mBlockLinks; //contiene i blocchi (i link con le info)

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final LinearLayout myContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.my_container); //layout presente nell'mainLayout
        mBlockLinks = new ArrayList<>();

        mFirstBlock = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.first_block);//R.id.first_block is the id layout of the block that I include in main Layout
        mDeleteLink = (ImageButton) mFirstBlock.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_delete_link);
        mDeleteLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myContainer.removeView((View) v.getParent());
                mBlockLinks.remove( v.getParent());
            }
        });

        mBlockLinks.add(mFirstBlock);

        mAddLink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add_link);
        mAddLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ViewGroup new_block = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_block_input, myContainer, false);
                myContainer.addView(new_block);
                mBlockLinks.add(new_block);

                mDeleteLink = (ImageButton) new_block.findViewById(R.id.imageButton_delete_link);
                mDeleteLink.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    //cancello il link relativo al bottone
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        myContainer.removeView((View) v.getParent());
                        mBlockLinks.remove( v.getParent());
                    }
                });

            }
        });

        mResult = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_subnetting);
        mResult.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),ResultActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_BLOCKS,mBlockLinks);
                startActivity(intent); //the line where appear the Exception
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have write only the code that most importat for me for resolve this problem.

Logcat error is below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value android.widget.RelativeLayout{42763ed8 V.E..... ......I. 0,176-656,352}
  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1235)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeList(Parcel.java:622)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1195)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeMapInternal(Parcel.java:591)
  at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1646)
  at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:605)
  at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:7353)
  at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:2222)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1436)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3464)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3425)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:842)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3661)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3629)
  at giusso.simone.indirizzamentoipsubnettingrete.IPActivity$5.onClick(IPActivity.java:122)
  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I read a lot of question where the problem was solved with the serializable interface that it was used for the class that it was passed for a new activity but in this case I don't know a method for solved this problem.

Thank for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass views, like `ViewGroup`, between activities.

If those activities are that tightly coupled, combine them into a single activity, using fragments or other techniques.

Comment: I have an activity for get the input with the ViewGroup. This input I want transfer at new activity for make calculations a then show the result. Maybe I must do a class with all the input of ViewGroup? 
It can be a good solution?

Comment: @Chuck94: "This input I want transfer at new activity for make calculations a then show the result" -- the "input" is not views. The input comes in the form of strings (e.g., what the user types into an `EditText`), boolean (e.g., the state of a `CheckBox`), and so on. You are welcome to pass that input (strings, booleans, etc.) to the other activity.

Comment: I'm sorry, with view I was referring a EditText. Therefore I have two EditText input that referr at an object. I don't want create two string array. Maybe it's better create a new class with a costructor that get the input of EditText. For example:   <pre> public class result implements serializable(if necessary){<br/>String editTextinput1; <br/>String editTextinput2; <br/>public Result(String input1,String input2){<br/>editTextinput1 = input1;<br/>editTextinput2 = input2}  ... }<code>. It's more clear the my idea?

Comment: @Chuck94: It would be simpler just to use two string extras, instead of one.